# How should I compare URIs in Java?

Tags: java, uri

I have a service class which gates certain URIs and allows them to bypass certain checks.
To do this, I'm adding a list of allowed URIs in a map with the action allowed, as so:

```
    private static final Map<String, Set<String>> ALLOWED_URIS =
        ImmutableMap.<String, Set<String>>builder()
                    .put("https://myurl.com/foo", ImmutableSet.of("GET"))
                    .put("https://anotherurl/bar", ImmutableSet.of("GET"))
                    .put("https://example.com/foo2", ImmutableSet.of("GET"))
                    .build();
```

It's not clear to me how I should compare a string URI to this, because URIs can potentially end in `/` or have query parameters or be case insensitive on domain name etc.

Say the input I receive is `https://myurl.com/foo?key=value`, the comparison would fail here because there's no key in the map that's equal to it.

```
    private static boolean isAllowed(final String uri, final String action) {
        return ALLOWED_URIS.getOrDefault(uri, emptySet()).contains(action);
    }
```

What's the best way to do my comparison? Is there a utility class available for this?

Comment: You can use regex (Regular Expression)

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea so would I use a pattern as a key here instead of a string?

Comment: www.yoursite.com/*

Comment: You could also just use the [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class and compare the parts of the URL you want to compare.

Comment: @Jesse would comparing scheme/host/port be enough?

Comment: Or use [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#compareTo(java.net.URI)) . Look at the javadoc for discussions on equality. If it doesn't fit the bill in its equality operation, you could make a wrapper class for it to use for your map key